# Identifying interaction responsible for this particular Eta-prime decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elementary-particles

$$\eta ' \rightarrow  \eta  + \pi^{-} + \pi^{+}$$

To identity the interaction responsible for the above reaction/ decay, observe that the *strangeness* number sums to zero on both sides. Conservation of *strangeness* therefore holds
This implies the interaction can only be either via the *strong* or electromagnetic interaction.
Is it possible nail the specific interaction given just the above information?
Obviously, in order to nail down the specific interaction, information regarding the decay times would be required.

Comment: Weak interaction CAN conserve strangeness. It just doesn't have to.

See this: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/conservation-of-strangeness-outside-of-strong-interactions.601577/

Comment: That effectively removed the only leg for my argument.

Comment: Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to give my best shot and say the presence of hardrons as a decay product is an indication that makes the strong interaction more involved than is the weak interaction.